# Send stdin to a deferred process?

Tags: process

I want to start a deferred process with: `deferred:process` and send text to to it. I can't work out how to do this looking at the source code.

Is this possible?

For context this came up when using `python-environment-run` which using `deferred`.

Comment: Are you talking about `C-h i g (elisp)JSONRPC deferred requests` ?  That's the closest thing I could see in the manual to `deferred:process` (but also not actually a match).  If not, please clarify what you specifically mean by "a deferred process", and what `deferred:process` refers to.  Show some code, please -- there is no `python-environment-run` in standard Emacs.

Comment: I guess `python-environment-run` is using [emacs-deferred](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred). I am not sure what you like to achieve, but if you'd like to communicate with some external python program, then have a look at [python-epc](https://github.com/tkf/python-epc), it is great!

Comment: I have a command line utility that mostly by being called with arguments, but it has a login step as well and the linux programmer me says "don't send username and password through command line arguments". This means I want to send them over standard in. Yeah I could use `python-epc` or indeed `http` it just feels like overkill and I'm prefer to have one utility that I use at the command line and with emcs.